# Trying to find duplicate Model_Number

Tags: mysql

Here is my query, but it shows unique model_number

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_name` 
GROUP BY Model_Number
HAVING COUNT( Model_Number ) >1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query worked

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_name` 
INNER JOIN (

SELECT Model_Number
FROM  `table_name` 
GROUP BY Model_Number
HAVING COUNT( id ) >1
)dup ON table_name.Model_Number = dup.Model_Number
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I see nothing seriously wrong with this answer; it seems to achieve the desired result.  I'm upvoting; will the down-voter please explain?

Comment: This query could be sped up by moving the `LIMIT` into the derived subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'id' is the primary key for your table, you query should be :

```
SELECT Model_Number,COUNT(id) as nbr_of_dup_Model_Number 
FROM  `table_name` 
GROUP BY  Model_Number
HAVING COUNT( id ) >1
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is the same as `COUNT(id)` except that it won't need to test `id` for being non-NULL.

Comment: It just to show that we need  number of rows for each Model_Number not   COUNT(Model_Number). (id identify a row)